# validation for email and mobile no in single inputbox using angularjs

Tags: angularjs-ng-pattern

How can  I validate  emailid and mobile no both  in a single input box in `AngulaJS`?

I'm trying to validate emaild and mobile no in same input box. it is working fine seperately, but for both emaild and mobile it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to verify the input using AngularJS (not the safest way to do it if it's the only check, making a second check in PHP/back-end/server side is recommanded).

You can use regular expression to filter the email and the phone number. You might want to check out `ng-pattern`

[AngularJS Official documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)

Emails and AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/txtuz2xn/4/

Phone number will vary from a country to another. Up to you to see how you want your regex to go.

If you want to have 1 input that checks either the phone or the email you could set up `$scope.regex1 = ...` and `$scope.regex2 = ...` and check regex2 if regex1 fails.

Comment: Jean as you said I tired with $scope.regex1 and $scope.regex2  .But it is validating only once for email or mobile no .When after writing email I am using backspace button to delete it and write mobile no its not working .How can i fixed that?? There is no backspace event in angular ..